# Force an element to be 100% height when the parent is shimmed taller by another child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here I have a parent div containing two children. Child 1 is set to 100% height, but it does not display at the actual height of parent, because child 2 is forcing the parent div taller.

```
<div style="height: 50px; width:106px">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; display: flex">
    &nbsp;
    <span style="border: 1px solid blue; height: 100%;">Child 1</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100px;">Child 2</span>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I get child 1 to match the *actual* height of the parent div in this scenario? I want to do this with pure HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47276375/3597276) is correct in terms of the solution, but the explanation is incorrect.

You have a flex container.

The container has two span children: span1 and span2.

span1 is set to `height: 100%`

span2 is set to `height: 100px`.

Because span1 is set to `height: 100%` and the flex container has no defined height, this element computes to `height: auto` (the height of the content).

Here is a more complete explanation of how this works:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

However, a default setting on a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that flex items will expand to cover the length of the container's [*cross axis*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276), which would be the height in this case.

But this default setting is overridden by the `height` property on flex items.

Therefore, remove `height: 100%` so `align-items: stretch` can work.

Now you have two equal height columns.

```html
<div style="height: 50px;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; display: inline-flex; padding: 5px;">
    <span style="border: 1px solid blue;">Child 1</span>
    <span style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100px; margin-left: 5px;">Child 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

your issue is because your child1 is inherit from parent. if you set it 100%, means the size of your child 1 will be 50px. to make it auto remove your child 1 `height: 100%;`
below is a sample.

```
<div style="height: 50px; width:106px">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; display: flex">
    &nbsp;
    <span style="border: 1px solid blue;">Child 1</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span style="border: 1px solid green; height: 100px;">Child 2</span>
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```